# How can i appropriately serve a static js file integrated with flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am currently going through the Web Programming with Python and Javascript via EDX. Specifically, I am on the part utilizing Socket.IO. I have come across an error that I am not quite sure how to fix and was wondering if anyone could help. This is source code from the course itself.

The file structure:

```
-venv
     -static
            -index.js
     -templates
            -index.html
     -application.py
```

Here is application.py:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

votes = {"yes": 0, "no": 0, "maybe": 0}


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", votes=votes)


@socketio.on("submit vote")
def vote(data):
    selection = data["selection"]
    votes[selection] += 1
    emit("vote totals", votes, broadcast=True)
```

Here is index.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // When connected, configure buttons
    socket.on('connect', () => {

        // Each button should emit a "submit vote" event
        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
            button.onclick = () => {
                const selection = button.dataset.vote;
                socket.emit('submit vote', {'selection': selection});
            };
        });
    });

    // When a new vote is announced, add to the unordered list
    socket.on('vote totals', data => {
        document.querySelector('#yes').innerHTML = data.yes;
        document.querySelector('#no').innerHTML = data.no;
        document.querySelector('#maybe').innerHTML = data.maybe;
    });
});
```

Here is index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='index.js')}}"></script>
    <title>Vote</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>Yes Votes: <span id="yes">{{ votes["yes"] }}</span></div>
    <div>No Votes: <span id="no">{{ votes["no"] }}</span></div>
    <div>Maybe Votes: <span id="maybe">{{ votes["maybe"] }}<span></div>
        <hr>
        <button data-vote="yes">Yes</button>
        <button data-vote="no">No</button>
        <button data-vote="maybe">Maybe</button>      
    </body>

</html>
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the application as is doesn't work. It will only work if I directly insert the js directly into the HTML file. For some reason serving it as a static file doesn't work. When I try to serve it as a static file I do have a console error stating "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null". I am assuming the issue is that the content isn't loaded by the time the script runs however moving the script around on the html page does not seem to do anything. Does any have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to insert `index.js` into a `js` folder in the `static` folder and moving the script to the bottom of the body.

Final HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js">
    </script>
    <title>Vote</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>Yes Votes: <span id="yes">{{ votes["yes"] }}</span></div>
    <div>No Votes: <span id="no">{{ votes["no"] }}</span></div>
    <div>Maybe Votes: <span id="maybe">{{ votes["maybe"] }}<span></div>
        <hr>
        <button data-vote="yes" id="yesvote">Yes</button>
        <button data-vote="no" id="novote">No</button>
        <button data-vote="maybe" id="maybevote">Maybe</button>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/index.js')}}"></script>    
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to put the javascript files in the `static/js` folder. Also, the reason you are getting `cannot set property of undefined` is a  problem in your HTML code where you set an id to the number of votes. You are supposed to set an id to the button tags. Here is the solution:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='index.js')}}"></script>
    <title>Vote</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>Yes Votes: <span>{{ votes["yes"] }}</span></div>
    <div>No Votes: <span>{{ votes["no"] }}</span></div>
    <div>Maybe Votes: <span>{{ votes["maybe"] }}<span></div>
        <hr>
        <button data-vote="yes" id="yes">Yes</button>
        <button data-vote="no" id="no">No</button>
        <button data-vote="maybe" id="yes">Maybe</button>      
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Varun, thank you so much for the quick response. Unfortunately after trying your recommended changes it still does not seem to work. Would you be able to clarify your second point?

My understanding is that id on the spans are just used in order to append html. Setting id on the button doesn't do anything as I believe the js code is to be dynamically set upon loading of the page and then utilizes dataset for the id basically. If the js script is implemented on the same page as the HTML, this error doesn't exist.

Comment: Hey again, appreciate the tip about the static/js folder. Doing this along with moving the script tag at the bottom of the body has fixed the error. Much appreciated in the point in the right direction!